# Calculate Average between MySQL results

Tags: php, mysql, date

I need to calculate the avg days between date of sales:

My DB is like this:

```
id | customer | creation_date | payment_date
1  |     234  |  2017/07/6    |  2017/07/8 
34  |     234  |  2017/08/4    |  2017/08/10 
53  |     234  |  2017/09/15   |  2017/09/17 
67  |     234  |  2017/10/1    |  2017/07/6
```

So I need to calculate de difference of days (creation_date) between Order 1 and Order 34, Order 34 and Order 53, Order 53 and Order 67, etc...

and calculate an AVG of days depending the number of results.

So I know how to calculate the difference of days between 2 dates using this small script:

```
$seconds=strtotime($date1) - strtotime($date2); 
$difference=intval($seconds/60/60/24); 
$positive = $difference * -1;
```

but I don´t know how to take the date of the las result and compare it with the next result.

Please someone who can help me with this enigma. Thanks!

Comment: I really wouldn't bother with the small script

Answer (score 4):

I could be misunderstanding what you are looking for, but I would think something like this should work

`(TO_DAYS(MAX(creation_date))-TO_DAYS(MIN(creation_date))) / (COUNT(1)-1)`

This will get you the total days between the first and last; and divide by the number of "spaces" between orders.

Edit: ....and if you wanted to treat orders on the same date as a single order, you can just change `COUNT(1)` to `COUNT(DISTINCT creation_date)`.

...all this assumes the db designer was sane and actually used DATE data types for date values.

---

To summarize, the average of the span sizes should be the same as the total span divided by the number of spans.

Comment: This is actually a really succinct solution.

Comment: I should use this line inside the SQL query, right?

Comment: @GuillermoEsquivel that is the intent yes; but if it is easier and you already have the individual data for the records in code; the `(max-min)/(count-1)` math should still work out for you the same.

Comment: Used this, but not sure if the syntax it's correct:  

`$query = "SELECT (TO_DAYS(MAX(creation_date))-TO_DAYS(MIN(creation_date))) / (COUNT(1)-1) AS promedio WHERE cid = '$cid'";`

Comment: @GuillermoEsquivel it looks right to me; assuming cid represents the "data dimension" for which you want the average date span between orders... and the `creation_date` field is correctly named (since your question did not include a `cid` field, it leaves me wondering).

Comment: Sorry, $cid is the "customer" id:

`$query = "SELECT (TO_DAYS(MAX(creation_date))-TO_DAYS(MIN(creation_date))) / (COUNT(1)-1) AS promedio WHERE customer = '$customer'";`

Comment: 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE `pedidos.cid` = 80'

Comment: Also tried with this but still not working:

`SELECT ((TO_DAYS(MAX(pedidos.creation_date))-TO_DAYS(MIN(pedidos.creation_date))) / (COUNT(1)-1)) WHERE pedidos.customer = '$cid'`

Comment: @GuillermoEsquivel your query has no `FROM pedidos`.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep track of the previous result using a variable outside of the loop to get your MySQL table and then run the loop through the rows of the table:

```
$last_positive = 0;
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $date1 = $row['creation_date'];
    $date2 = $row['payment_date'];
    $seconds=strtotime($date1) - strtotime($date2); 
    $difference=intval($seconds/60/60/24); 
    $positive = abs($difference);
    //DO SOME COMPARISON HERE
    echo($last_positive >= $positive);

    $last_positive = $positive;
}
```

I'd also suggest using `abs` to get the absolute value instead of multiplying by -1.

Comment: If using PHP, I'd be inclined to use `DateTime::diff`.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED WITH THIS:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(MAX(creation_date), MIN(creation_date)) / (COUNT(creation_date) - 1) AS SaleAverage FROM table WHERE customer = '$customer'
```